# Django - possible to display ImageField objects in static folder?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-staticfiles, django-models

This is my settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
 STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/userName/project/app/static',
)
```

Suppose my view is passing an ImageField object to the template. So as described here in the docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url

I can access the URL of the image by doing

```
 {{ FieldFile.url }}
```

in my template. It works if I try to access the URL of the image, however, I need to be able to load static as well. I want to do something like this:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<img src="{% static "{{ FieldFile.url }}" %}" alt="" />
```

however, that does not work. Suppose the FieldFile.url is

```
images/imageName.jpg
```

and when I do

```
<img src="{% static "images/imageName.jpg" %}" alt="" />
```

it works, but it doesn't work when I use

```
{{ FieldFile.url }}
```

for some reason, how come?

Note: when I try to do

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<img src="{% static "{{ FieldFile.url }}" %}" alt="" />
```

and 'inspect element' using google chrome, it shows this

```
<img src="/static/%7B%7B%20FieldFile.url%20%7D%7D" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `{{ }}` are not necessary since you are already inside a template tag:

```
<img src="{% static FieldFile.url %}" alt="" />
```